# Little trouble with Vuex in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I have a simple doubt and is that I don't know why **this works:**

store/topics.js

```
export const state = () => ({
  list:[]
})

import slugify from "limax"
export const mutations = {
  ADD_TOPIC(state, title, subtitle){
    state.list.push({
      title,
      subtitle,
      id: Date.now(),
      ...
    })
  },
...
```

topics/new.vue

```
import {mapMutations} from 'vuex'
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      title: '',
      subtitle: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addTopic(title, subtitle){
      this.$store.commit('topics/ADD_TOPIC', title, subtitle)
    },
...
```

And this, doesn't works:

store/topics.js

```
export const state = () => ({
  list:[]
})

export const mutations = {
  ADD_TOPIC(state, topic){
    state.list.push(topic)
  },
...
```

topics/new.vue

```
import {mapMutations} from 'vuex'
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      topic: {
        title: '',
        subtitle: '',
        id: Date.now(),
        ...
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addTopic(topic){
      this.$store.commit('topics/ADD_TOPIC', topic)
    },
...
```

The thing in the second case is that when I push a topic, it's pushed correctly in the array... But when I go to add the next one, is like a duplicate :S And when I write something in the inputs updates all duplicated objects of the array.

Comment: I guess this happens because of they are all same objects. Try `this.$store.commit('topics/ADD_TOPIC', { ...topic }) ` this will send the new object every times you commit.

Comment: From your previous comment, I want you to be a little more careful when using this. The spread syntax it's a Shallow-cloning. See more https://medium.com/@manjuladube/youve-spent-so-many-years-looking-forward-to-this-phase-of-your-life-37810684a38c